# How to cast void* struct members?

Tags: c, string, casting

I'm trying to cast a `void*` from a struct member. The struct looks like this:

```
typedef struct{
    int n;
    void* string;
}query;
```

And I want to cast the member `string` to `char*` and store another string -- lets say `str2`--, like this:

```
char* str2 = "hello";
(*(char*)q.string) = str2;
```

But it keeps telling me this warning:

> example.c: In function ‘main’:
>   example.c:23:33: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
>        (* (char* )q.string) = str2;

Why is this isn't working?

Comment: I think the warning is reported because of indirection operator applied to q.string pointer. You try to assign str2 pointer value (address) to the first byte of a memory area q.string points to. Correct way would be: q.string = str2;

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a cast, at all.

That said, in your example, `query` is a type, not a variable.

Use it like

```
query q;
q.string = str2;
```

[A working example](https://ideone.com/QdI2CX)

Comment: Yes!! Sorry my bad, i wrote it wrong it is indeed a type, and i know that i don't really need to cast, but it is for a task and requires that i need to cast void*

Comment: @NikosC. Why it "should" be `const`? It can be fine without one, too.

Comment: @NikosC. No problem, comments are gone.

Comment: @luciofondon Did you check the example I provided? Is that something you want?

Comment: I undestand that it is not need the cast because it works with the example that you post, but the thing is that the task requires that i have to cast it, and i want to know that if i was doing the cast properly, sorry for my bad english by the way!

Comment: @luciofondon as far as I can understand, I don't see why you need the cast in first place. Can you show the actual scenario where you need to cast? Maybe we can help then

Comment: I have a homework from university and it requires me to save a string into the member of the struct void* string, and this is because i need to make the types match properly and make use of the casting, I don't know if i explained right, I'm a little bit confused

Comment: @luciofondon `it requires me to save a string into the member of the struct void* string,`..that's what I just shown in my example, you would not need a cast.

Comment: That said, casting the left hand side operand is almost never a requirement.

Answer (score 1):

The warning is correct. Newer versions of gcc have a more helpful message:

> warning: assignment to 'char' from 'char *' makes
>   integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
>
> ```
> 13 |     (*(char*)q.string) = str2;
>    |                        ^
> ```

You dereference a `char *` which gives you a `char`. To that `char` type you assign `str2` which is of type `char *`.

As [Sourav Ghosh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55508659/2805305) showed you, you can just do this:

```
q.string = str2;
```

If you really want to make the cast explicit:

```
q.string = (void*)str2;
```

As you see you were doing the cast on the wrong side.